# How do I get Expression.PropertyOrField to work for a child?

Tags: c#, expression

I've been working with `Expression`s all day and my code to generically do `c => c.Name` for example has finally worked. The user can specify a property e.g. `"Name"` as a string and I use this:

```
var selectorParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "c");
var selector = Expression.PropertyOrField(selectorParameter, memberName);
```

To get it.

However I just discovered that in some cases I need to do not just `c.Name` but something like `c.Address.AddressLine1` where memberName is `"Address.AddressLine1"`. The latter does not work.

Is there a way to handle these nested instances with children as part of the selector?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can decompose it yourself, like this:

```
var selectorParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "c");
MemberExpression selector = null;
// first part goes to parameter - "x.Parameter"
Expression current = selectorParameter;
foreach (var part in memberName.Split('.')) {
    selector = Expression.PropertyOrField(current, part);
    // subsequent parts go to selector itself: "x.Parameter.AnotherParameter"
    current = selector;
}
```

If you want to ensure all those properies actually exists, you can do it like that:

```
var selectorParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "c");
MemberExpression selector = null;
Expression current = selectorParameter;
Type currentType = typeof(T);
foreach (var part in memberName.Split('.')) {
    var prop = currentType.GetProperty(part, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
    if (prop == null) {
        // do something
    }
    selector = Expression.Property(current, prop);
    current = selector;
    currentType = prop.PropertyType;
}
```

Comment: Ah, cool - thank you very much! Would you happen to know if there's a way to test if it a property exists without doing a try/catch?